# Strong gravity at the Planck scale?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

I have read this question:

[Why do quantum effects of gravity become important at the Planck scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366598/why-do-quantum-effects-of-gravity-become-important-at-the-planck-scale)

[What does quantum gravity look like at or beyond the Planck scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163665/what-does-quantum-gravity-look-like-at-or-beyond-the-planck-scale)

[Gravity and Planck scale](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28238/gravity-and-planck-scale?rq=1)

[What is the relationship between a gravitational wave and a graviton?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375124/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-gravitational-wave-and-a-graviton)

And the answer where it says:

> at very small distances of the order of the Planck length (∼10−35m), gravity becomes very strong

None of these questions says whether gravity is stronger or not at that scale.

Question:

1. Is it correct that gravity becomes strong at the Planck scale?

Comment: The short answer is nobody knows, because we don't have any experimental data even close to that scale. Was there a particular theory of quantum gravity that you wanted this question answered with?

Comment: I only know string theory. Is there anything in string theory that says gravity becomes stronger at the Planck scale?